# If $f(x) \to 0$ and $g$ is a bounded function, then $f(x)g(x) \to 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am using a non-English source text so I am not sure that all technical terms is given their correct English name.

What my source text calls "upper limited function" is defined as a function that has an upper limited range, that is, there is a B such that

$\forall x \in D_{f}: f(x) \leq B$

**Question 1**: What is the correct English name for this term?

I came across the following theorem:

If $\lim f(x) = 0$ and the function $g(x)$ is limited (i.e. both "upper limited" and "lower limited"), then $f(x)g(x) \rightarrow 0$

**Question 2**: Is there a specific name for this theorem?

The proof of this theorem starts by stating that the requirement that g(x) is limited for large x implies that there exists numbers $C$ and $\omega_{0}$, such that:

$$x > \omega_{0} \rightarrow | g(x)| < C $$

Then they define $ \epsilon $ as a positive number and the assumptions behind $f(x)$ means that there is a number $\omega_{1}$, such that

$$x > \omega_{1} \rightarrow | f(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{C} $$

Now, if $\omega = \max(\omega_{0},\omega_{1})$, then

$$x > \omega \rightarrow |f(x)g(x)| = |f(x)||g(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{C} \cdot C = \epsilon$$

This apparently means exactly that $f(x)g(x) \rightarrow 0$ when $x \rightarrow \infty$

**Question 3**: I do not really understand that much of this proof, such as the the part about assumptions behind $f(x)$ implies the things it does or how the part about $\omega = \max(\omega_{0},\omega_{1})$ follows. Any tips?

**Question 4**: I sometimes find myself dealing with non-English source texts for a variety of reasons. Any advice on how to connect knowledge gained from these texts to the larger knowledge amassed from English literature?

Comment: Where you say "limited" I would say "bounded".

Comment: And 'upper limited' would be 'bounded above'. About question 4, just go on your native language's wikipedia page for a given subject and switch to english.

Comment: Is this PB, Analys i en variabel? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean $ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = 0$ and $ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)g(x) = 0 $ and let $ a = \infty $.

**Ad Question 3**: To me this seems to be a basic proof of a convergence via the $ \varepsilon $-criterion.

Let $ \overline{\varepsilon} \gt 0 $.

Make sure you know the definition of convergence regarding a function.

Limited in the context of a function $ g(x) $ means, that there exists a constant C so that for every $ \varepsilon \gt 0 $:

$$ \exists \overline x_g : \forall x > \overline x_g, x \in \mathbb{D}_{g(x)}  : |g(x) - C| \lt \varepsilon $$

$ \mathbb{D}_{g(x)} $ means the domain of $ g(x) $, e.g. the domain of $ \ln(x) $ for real values $ x $ is normally $ \mathbb{R}^{+} \setminus \{ 0 \} $.

We know that $ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = 0 $, which implies that for every $\varepsilon$ we can find a $ \overline x_f \in \mathbb{D}_{f(x)} $ so that:
$$ \forall x \gt \overline x_f, x \in \mathbb{D}_{f(x)}:  |f(x)| < \varepsilon $$

As with all proofs where you can find an $ \varepsilon $ you now have to tweak the $ \varepsilon $ to fit your needs.

$ \varepsilon = \frac{\overline{\varepsilon}}{C} $ will do it.

You want to make sure that starting from $ \overline x $ every other $ x \gt \overline x $ satisfies $ |f(x)g(x)| \lt \overline\varepsilon $.

So you must pick the Maximum of the $ \overline x_f $ from $ f(x) $ and the $ \overline x_g $ from $ g(x) $ because for $ x \gt \max(\overline x_f, \overline x_g) $ both implications will be satisfied and we can derive the last inequality I marked with (*).

$$ \forall x \gt \max(\overline x_f, \overline x_g): |f(x)g(x)| = |f(x)| |g(x)| \overset{(*)}{\lt} \frac{\overline{\varepsilon}}{C} \cdot C = \overline{\varepsilon} $$

Therefore: $ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)g(x) = 0 $.

**Ad Question 4**: I'm a german and find myself reading english source texts for my studies very often. After a short time I learned to deal with the correspondences of math in german and math in english. (Maybe it is easier for a german because many things in analysis or algebra are almost the same in english and german - eigenvalues, Galois-Theory, many definitions in measure theory, etc.)

Just always try to make the connection between the things you read in your native tongue and how you name them in english.